# how to create an instance from a class that extends comparable and implement generic interface?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have a class that extends comparable and implements a generic interface  and I want to create an instance of that class .

for example

```
interface MinMax<T extends Comparable<T>> {...}

class Employee<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MinMax<T> {...}
```

in this example i want to create an instance of Employee , how is that possible ?

Comment: `new Employee<String>()` or `new Employer<Integer>`, for example. You simply need to provide a type variable within the bounds. (Depending on the context, `new Employee<>()` might work too).

Answer (score 2):

`Employee` doesn't need to take a type parameter. You want to make it `Comparable`  and then use it as the type argument for `MinMax`:

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>, MinMax<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee e) {
        //compare and return...
    }
}
```

With that, you don't need a type parameter for employee:

```
Employee e = new Employee(); //or whatever constructor you declared...
```